# Reason for an #include

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    printf("Enter 2 numbers:\n");

    scanf("%d", &num1);
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    if (num1 == num2){
      printf("Equal");     
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

The tutorial has this: `#include <conio.h>`

i tried it without `#include <conio.h>` and works ok...

But why did he put it? [here is this tutorial.](http://www.thenewboston.com/?p=125&pOpen=tutorial)

Comment: Do you know what `#include` means and what it is ordinarily used for?

Answer (score 3):

Because in the tutorial it is `getch()` not `getchar()`.

`getch()` is declared in `conio.h`, whereas `getchar()` is declared in `stdio.h`.

Comment: look it did not included auto ..i puted because i saw it on the tutorial. but then i tried it without this because in the hello world there is not the conio, and worked the same...so i am wondering

Comment: +1 but `getch()` (and `getchar()`) is not defined in `<conio.h>` (and `<stdio.h>`). Its definition is part of the implementation and it is **declared** in `<conio.h>`/`<stdio.h>`

Answer (score 2):

`conio.h` is a non-standard header that was shipped with many old C compilers for MS-DOS.  It is not necessary in the code you posted, as none of that code requires its definitions.  If including it produces an error, that is because `conio.h` is not available on your system.  You may want to consult a more up-to-date tutorial if the one you're using is referencing DOS-specific headers.

Edit: Ouch, just looked at the linked tutorial.  2009?  Someone is including `conio.h` as boilerplate C code in a tutorial from *2009*?  What a cruel world this is.

Comment: Probably stole the code from a *...For Dummies* book. They're quite well-known for crimes like this.

Answer (score 1):

All the functions you are using are defined in stdio.h, it doesn't seem to use anything that is inside conio.h, thus rendering it useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It works because all the functions used in the code - `scanf, printf, getchar` - are declared in [`stdio.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdio.h.html).